# javascript jquery accessing the element being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following list of semibuttons loaded using javascript:

```
        var html ='<ul class="nav well-tabs well-tabs-inverse mb10" id="users">';

        html +='<li class="active"><a id="'+this.my.user+'" data-toggle="tab_'+self.my.id+'" class="pestaña">'+this.my.user+'</a></li>';
        var users = this.my.community_users;
        for (i=0;i<users.length;i++) {
            if (users[i].user != this.my.user)
            html +='<li><a id="'+users[i].user+'" data-toggle="tab_'+self.my.id+'" class="pestana">'+users[i].user+'</a></li>';
        };
        html +='</ul>';
        $(html).appendTo("#Dashboard");
```

Note, that the first item in the list is active. I am getting something like this:

[image]

Ok, now i code he onclick event to do something when a button is clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-toggle=tab_'+self.my.id+']', function(e){
      // whatever here
});
```

What I need now is to set active the tab being clicked and set inactive the tab that was active. How can I access both elements to addclass and removeclass active?

Comment: `var html +=` is basically wrong. Should be `var html =`. Or define it before concatenating using `var html = "";`

Comment: Could you setup fiddle?

Comment: @Egidi even if corrected now, your question cannot be reproduced in a manner that one could play with. So... please show more.

Comment: FYI, you are using two different classes, `pestaña` and `pestana`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use following logic:

```
$(document).on('click', '#users li:not(.active)', function () {
    $('#users').find('li.active').add(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. Basically remove the `.active` class from everything but the element you clicked on. The add the `.active` class to the element clicked on.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-toggle=tab_'+self.my.id+']', function (e) {
    $('a[data-toggle=tab_'+self.my.id+']').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the 'active' class from all the list items first, then add it back to just the only that was clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-toggle=tab_'+self.my.id+']', function (e) {
    $('#users .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```